# Is fever a countable or uncountable noun?

Tags: nouns

I have some difficulties in using the noun 'fever'. Is it countable or uncountable? Is it correct to say "They have fevers."?

Comment: Singular and plural are both fine. Google books has 6 instances of [*the children have **fevers***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+children+have+fevers%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 9 of [*the children have **fever***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+children+have+fever%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example.

Answer (score -1):

As with many words in English (it's a mongrel language, after all) [uncountable nouns](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/) can sometimes be a bit tricky. Although uncountables are usually singular, this is not always the case, fear being another example, and "fever" fall into this category. "They have fevers" is entirely correct, but "she has fevers" is not - it's one per customer, even if the patient has multiple conditions, each of which produces a fever.

And just to make things interesting, a usage exists which does quantify fever, "N degrees of fever", although this seems to have pretty much fallen out of favor.

Comment: People also say _a fever of 103_ when they mean _a temperature of 103_.

Comment: Countability is not an intrinsic property of an English noun, like gender is in German or French. Most nouns can be used as either mass or count, depending on the construction they're used in. The constructions mean different things, depending on what's being talked about, and the nouns can refer to masses or to individuated things.

Comment: I think "one per customer" should be "one per customer at any one time." "She has fevers every few months" sounds OK to me.